# How can i change footer color without affecting menu bar color in my site

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i change footer color without affecting menu bar color.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to send a url ?

Comment: now am using localhost bro.

Comment: am changing either footer or menu, it can be affected both color

Comment: referrer the answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure CSS question and is not related to Magento.

Comment: At the very least you have to provide the class names and probably CSS hierarchy of the target blocks. Add those to your question & nominate for reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class for a footer and your css rule in css file.

open footer file located at `app\design\frontend\<PACKAGE_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\template\page\html\footer.phtml`

add your class like `<div class="footer-container myCustomFooter">`

and in css file for ex. style.css add rule for this

```
.myCustomFooter{
background-color:#fff;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: not working bro,

Comment: come for a chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39990/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-ashish-madankar

Comment: try background-color:#fff !important;

Comment: i replied in chat

Answer (score 1):

Target the footer using is specific CSS selector. Such as:

```
.footer-container {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```